# How can I delete the available state in a local cache?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am working on an app that uses firebase's firestore  and was wondering if this is possible because I don't want my app to check for data that no longer exists in the server.
Example:

```
collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : snapshots) {
                System.out.println(snapshot.getId());
                // This prints document IDs of documents that were deleted
                // from the collection when the app was not running
            }
        }
    });
```

Using `DocumentSnapshot.exists()` to filter snapshots existing only in the server does not work

More info in [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen):

> The initial state can come from the server directly, or from a local cache. If there is state available in a local cache, the query snapshot will be initially populated with the cached data, then updated with the server's data when the client has caught up with the server's state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine if the snapshot comes from the cache by checking its metadata.

[`QuerySnapshot#getMetadata()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/QuerySnapshot.html#getMetadata()) returns a `SnapshotMetadata` object.
[`SnapshotMetadata#isFromCache()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/SnapshotMetadata.html#isFromCache()) returns a boolean if the snapshot is from the cache.

If you want to be notified whenever the metadata changes (so you can know if `isFromCache()` changes) then you have to pass options when you add the listener:

```
   // Create options
   QueryListenOptions options = new QueryListenOptions().includeDocumentMetadataChanges();

   // Pass them when you add the listener
   collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(options, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       // ...
   });
```

See the docs for [`addSnapshotListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryListenOptions,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E))