# Android - How to handle Firestore exceptions at user level?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in my app and I can't figure out how to handle at user level the exceptions thrown by that. (I mean what to display to the user when such exceptions occur).

For example, to perform any `CRUD` operation on Firestore ([`DocumentReference#get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)), [`DocumentReference#set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)), [`DocumentReference#update`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E))) a `Task` is returned, which might contain an exception, but in the documentation I can't find **why** this exception might be thrown by Firestore.

Is there something better that we can do, rather than simply log the exception and show a generic message like "an error occurred, please try again later"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the official documentation regarding [getting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), you can get the exception from the `task` object like this:

```
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            //Log the error if the task is not successful
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

And remember, a Task is `complete` when the work represented by the Task is finished, regardless of its `success` or `failure`. There may or may not have been an error, and you have to check for that. On the orter side, a Task is "successful" when the work represented by the task is finished, as expected, with no errors.

As @Raj mentioned in his answer, you can also use `addOnFailureListener` but note, if there is a loss of network connectivity (there is no network connection on user device), neither `onSuccess()` nor `onFailure()` are triggered. This behavior makes sense, since the task is only considered completed when the data has been committed (or rejected) on the Firebase server. `onComplete(Task<T> task)` method is called also only when the Task completes. So in case of no internet connection, neither `onComplete` is triggered.

Comment: I've checked better the docs for `DocumentReference#get` method, and it says that the task can fail if the document cannot be retrieved neither from server nor from local cache. So, I've understood that if there is a loss of network connectivity and the document is not cached, the `onFailureListener`/`onCompleteListener` will be called anyway, am I right?

Comment: No! Let's take an example. [OnSuccessListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnSuccessListener) is an interface. An interface cannot be called. What can be called instead, is the method that exists in this interface, in this case `onSuccess()` method. But in case of no network connection on user device, neither `onSuccess()` nor `onFailure()` are triggered. One or the other will be called, only when the data has been committed (or rejected) by the Firebase servers, ok?

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: so if those callbacks (`onSuccess()` and `onFailure()`) are not called in that case, do I need to perform a check for network connectivity every time I need to read/write data in firestore?

Comment: No, there is no need for that. Every time you don't have internet connection, the data is read from the cache. There is a workaround for this, so please check my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894118/cant-disable-offline-data-in-firestore)**, to see how you can use `documentSnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache()`., to see if you are reading data from or Firebase servers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use onFailureListener() method of Firestore and get the errors while getting, setting or updating the data. In this example I have used it in setting data:-

```
firestore.collection("User").document(uid).set(user).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
        {
          //Data Saved Successfully
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e)
                {
                    //Toast error using method -> e.getMessage()

                }
            });
```

If you want to catch exceptions in firebase authentication module then refer:- [How to catch a Firebase Auth specific exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859582/how-to-catch-a-firebase-auth-specific-exceptions)

Comment: I've missed out `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener`, thank you