# Is there a potential bug getting error using Firestore query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So here are two situations when there is **no network**:

Withtout using any query I'm getting an error:

```
collectionReference.document().get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: success");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The same goes for `addOnFailureListener` where I'm able to log the errors for the above example i.e.:

```
Failed to get document because the client is offline
```

Now, while using **queries**, I get no error, examples:

```
collectionReference.limit(1).get().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
    }
});
```

Used the `limit` option. Other case examples:

```
collectionReference.addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: error"  + e);
        return;
    }

    if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: success");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: no result");
    }
});
```

Or using `document`:

```
collectionReference.document("path").addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshot, e) -> {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: error"  + e);
        return;
    }

    if (documentSnapshot != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: success");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: no result");
    }
});
```

Another one that returns `success`:

```
collectionReference.limit(1).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: success");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: error " + task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Current dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
```

All the above examples returns `success` even if it fails. So is this is a bug or that it's suppose to work like this?

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955413/android-how-to-handle-firestore-exceptions-at-user-level/51965256#51965256)** out and please responde with @.

Comment: Edited the post just now. However, for the top snippet, i.e. without query,  the error I get is `Failed to get document because the client is offline` but for other ones, it all logs `success`.

Comment: @Rajarshi Have you checked my answer from that post? Does it answer your question?

Comment: @AlexMamo I was doing a test run on what you told on provided link and sadly got both success and error messages, this makes it harder to debug. Why there is no any way to get the network status? **By the way**, what is `task.isComplete()` used for?

Comment: @Rajarshi Let's stick to one question at a time. You say you get "both success and error messages" but in which case? How does your code look like? That are the exact errors that you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo edited the question, see the last snippet, it suppose to do so as you explained

Comment: Using the last snippet, you cannot get both. You can either get `"onComplete: success"` or `"onComplete: error " + task.getException()`.  Maybe you get that error from another part of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178530/discussion-between-rajarshi-and-alex-mamo).