# When using Query for FirestoreRecyclerAdapter I am not calling get() but I need to set Query.get(Source.SERVER)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

In my android app I am using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` from [firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md)  which binds `Query` and `Model`. When app is off-line I need it to show nothing. But the app shows data from cache which is `DEFAULT` according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source)

I also tried to `.setPersistenceEnabled(false)` on `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` which didn't help.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894118/cant-disable-offline-data-in-firestore) I figured out that I need to use `get(Source.SERVER)` on `Query` but I am not using `get()` on my `query` as I am using it in `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`, which is used by `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`

Here is my code which is basically same as in [example app](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/firestore/FirestoreChatActivity.java) from firebaseui in lines 160-178.

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("files")
                .orderBy("timestamp")
                .limit(50);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FileToPrint> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FileToPrint>()
                .setQuery(query, FileToPrint.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FileToPrint, FileToPrintHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(FileToPrintHolder holder, int position, FileToPrint model) {
                // Bind the Chat object to the ChatHolder
                holder.bind(model);
            }

            @Override
            public FileToPrintHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                // layout called R.layout.message for each item
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.file_to_print_item, group, false);

                return new FileToPrintHolder(view);
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I disconnect the Internet I expect to see empty list, but instead I see this log:

> Firestore: (21.0.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
>
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

and

[image: not in sync screenshot]

Comment: How did you tried to use `.setPersistenceEnabled(false)` and it didn't work?

Comment: Not sure if I did it right but I put the following code right before the code in the post:  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
                .build();
        db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().setFirestoreSettings(settings);

Comment: It's right but what happened when you did this?

Comment: When I disconnect AVD from the Internet it still shows some items from the list. Also I am able to check/uncheck Checkboxes while my code changes state in firebase server. I should see that checkbox is changed its state ONLY after server changed it state of particular checkbox. So what I expect is that UI fully depend on server state or shows nothing otherwise

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache, use `.setPersistenceEnabled(false)` and read the data again? Does it work this way?

Comment: I just tried to use FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().clearPersistence();. For few seconds same behavior as before, part of items shown and checkable checkboxes, then application crashes saying "failed to connect to firestore.googleapis.com"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`
remove it this is **working for me**...just give it try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using adapter.startListening() and adapter.stopListening();