# Firestore listener get documents with DocumentChange.Type ADDED (ignore cached data)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add chat functionality to my app, and what I'm trying to do is listen to the messages that the other user sends after loading some old messages.

everything works fine, and I am aware of the fact that whenever a new document is added firebase download that document and adds it with the cached data then triggers the listener.

Of course, you have to add limit otherwise if the users chat for a few hours you'll end up getting back hundreds or maybe thousands of cached messages only to show 1 new message.

So let's say we add a limit of 50(I'll explain why 50), that way whenever the other user sends a new message we get 1 new message and 49 cached messages which we will ignore.

Alright, everything works fine like this, but what if we go offline and the other user sends messages? If the other user sends 10 messages while we are offline, then we go back online the listener will be triggered and we will download 10 new messages plus 40 cached messages, then what if the user sent 55 messages while we're offline? well when we go back online we will download only 50 new messages and we will not download the remaining 5 messages, this is my problem.

I can simply remove the limit but then if the users have thousands of cached messages I'll have to go through them every time a new message is sent which I think is really inefficient, the best solution will be to only get the newly added messages whenever the listener is triggered, the 50 limit that I am using now is only a simple workaround that doesn't work at all states.

Comment: Please, insert more ENTERs (carriage return) in your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

> what if the user sent 55 messages while we're offline? well when we go back online we will download only 50 new messages and we will not download the remaining 5 messages, this is my problem.

When we are talking about lots of messages we aren't only limiting the queries. As you have already noticed, if the limit is less than the number of messages received while offline, you'll only download that number of messages that is equal with your limitation. In such cases we are using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query). So the best option is to use in the first query the limitation (`limit(50)`) and in the fololowing queries the last visible document. In this way, when the user scrolls, he can download now those 5 messages that he couldn't see if we have used only a `limit(50)` call.

**Edit:**

You can still do it if you are using a snapshot listener. Check this out:

```
db.collection("yourColl").document("yourDoc").addSnapshotListener(new DocumentListenOptions().includeMetadataChanges(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        System.out.println("isFromCache: " + snapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache());
    }
});
```

Comment: from what I understood you're saying to get the 50th message and try to download 50 messages starting after the 50th message that is visible for the user.
if so then this is a possible solution but it isn't a clean one, isn't there any better ways?

Comment: Why do you say it isn't a clean? Almost every app in the world uses paginaion, one way or another. In case of Firestore, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) is how you can achieve it and in my opinion is a very clean and easy solution to implement.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, if the user goes out of the chat room then come back in and scroll up I will load the previous messages, I'm already implementing that(pagination).
my problem is while the user is still inside the chat room goes offline and then go online, without leaving that chat room.

Comment: What's wrong "while the user is still inside the chat room goes offline and then go online, without leaving that chat room."? I cannot see any problem in that situation.

Comment: I'm adding the new messages to the previous messages so let's say we have these messages inside the chat room 1 2 3 4 5 and the user sends  6 7 8 9 10, I'll just add these messages to the previous messages  like this 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, so in my case if the user sends 55 messages while offline, it will be something like this, the new messages are 11 12 13 .... 50 51 52 53 54 55. so when we add the messages to the previous messages this will happen.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (new messages)11 12 13 ..... 45 46 47 48 49 50 

we will end up not adding the latest 5 messages which are 51 52 53 54 55

Comment: Yes, you aren't loading the last 5 since the limit is set to 50. To load the other messages, the user needs to scroll in order to get the new onces. This is how pagination work. Let me give you an example. What if instead of 55 messages, there are 1000, are you willing to load all 1000 messages? I think that the answer is no, since it's not worth to load so many messages at once. The user might not even have the time to read them. Beside that is a waste of resources and reads. If the user is interested to read them all, he should scoll the messages and get them in smaller chunks, right?

Comment: I understand, as I mentioned before I am already doing this, I am only loading 20 messages at the start with get() then I start listening to the documents. please come over to the chat so I can clarify the problem to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199842/discussion-between-alex-mamo-and-motahir).

Comment: sadly no, it will be solved only if you're able to get only the data from the server without the cached ones

Comment: You can do that. You can get the data only from the server by passing `Source.SERVER` to the `get()` method. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894118/cant-disable-offline-data-in-firestore)** out. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I'm not using get, I am using snapshotListener

Comment: Yes you can. Please check my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: @MoTahir Hi again! Have you managed to solve the problem? Hope you did.

Comment: I apologize but the answer/comments won't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can add another field to your document to track that this message is new, received or read. then you can query all those message those are new, and non new messages with limit.
you-will make two queries like this.but this will work. or you can even decrease your non-new limit.

Comment: this won't be a good solution that way you will increase the number of writes you have to perform, I want to use the least read/writes possible